# Word/phrase to be used as banter for someone who writes walls of text?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, terminology

We have a guy who literally writes paragraphs and paragraphs of text in most of his forum posts. If I had to pull his leg and tag him as a `<insert placeholder here>`, what word or phrase would that be?

Comment: There is a vast difference between **(1)** criticising somebody for saying in an overelaborate way something that could have been said more concisely, without any loss of content, and **(2)** criticising somebody for writing something that is excessively long for the given setting (e.g. an Internet discussion board), even though it may be perfectly OK for a different setting (e.g. a scholarly journal). Which of the two do you have in mind?

Comment: @jsw29 (2) is the one I'm looking for. Although it isn't meant to be critical in nature. More like friendly banter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a [graphomaniac](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/graphomania#:%7E:text=%3A%20a%20compulsive%20urge%20to%20write):

> someone with a compulsive urge to write.

(MW)

Comment: That sounds like it.